# Flexbox wrap not working with multiple children divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use `flex: wrap;` on two divs but it only seems to work on the first div. Why is this? I know I can put everything in one div, but I would like to have everything organized.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)), url('https://d31qu3dhiv8md1.cloudfront.net/images/rust-leaves-early-access-1516667234.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="server-info">
    <div class="name">My Server</div>
    <div class="desc">This is the description</div>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Link1</a>
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you use the flexbox correctly.  [Here is the link to the  documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flexbox-display)

Comment: @JimmySurprenant how so?

Comment: @JimmySurprenant I'm not using Tail Wind CSS, whatever that is...

Comment: Sorry for assuming you were using it.

Please refer to this [CodePen instead](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaEzWj)

Choose the editor view and try to resize the example area to see flex:wrap in action

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is every flex items to be on top of each other? You can set `flex-direction` to `column` to both container like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)), url('https://d31qu3dhiv8md1.cloudfront.net/images/rust-leaves-early-access-1516667234.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.server-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="server-info">
    <div class="name">My Server</div>
    <div class="desc">This is the description</div>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Link1</a>
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the below is what you are after. I have done 2 things:

- Added a container div around the two divs inside the header. The flexbox now has one element that will be centered vertically and horizontally
- Made the width of the two containers 100%

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)), url('https://d31qu3dhiv8md1.cloudfront.net/images/rust-leaves-early-access-1516667234.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.server-info,
.links {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div>
    <div class="server-info">
      <div class="name">My Server</div>
      <div class="desc">This is the description</div>
    </div>

    <div class="links">
      <a href="#">Link1</a>
      <a href="#">Link2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```